# Chrome default profile opened with python wont get website

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

**So I created a code on python with selenium that opens up my default chrome profile browser, and it opens the profile 1 browser successfully, however after it opens the browser it wont load the website I have the get request to (in this case youtube.), and simply stays on the default google search/new tab page.... and I get the following error -- >

```py
raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
```

My program:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


print("starting")


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
print('options...')

options.add_argument('/Users/MyName/Library/Applications/Google/Chrome/Profile 1') #Path to your chrome profile
print('options.argument...')


driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome', chrome_options=options) #driver

driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
```

Comment: What version of python/selenium are you using? I believe the most recent versions have different syntax than what you're using, though I don't think it will solve your problem. ```options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=...")``` and ```webdriver.Chrome(options=options)```, not ```chrome_options```. Also make sure no other chrome windows are open using that profile when you run your code.

Comment: as @goalie1998 said be sure to end all the tasks by the task manage